# Validation loss consistently dropping even after training loss reached 0

Tags: python, validation, deep-learning, pytorch

Just as the title says, my model's training loss reached 0 and 100% accuracy at epoch 14 but the validation loss keeps on decreasing. Normally the case for me is that my validation loss usually reaches its minimum before the training loss reaches 0.
I've been trying out different variations of the model and encountered this kind of training behavior where validation loss keeps on decreasing even after the training loss reached 0.

So what's happening right now is

1. training loss reached 0 (100% accuracy) at epoch14
2. validation loss consistently drops. I'm at epoch 700 at the moment and the loss has been decreasing every epoch very slowly.

As I usually choose the best model based on minimum validation loss, the question is, should I keep on training the model until the validation loss stops decreasing?

Comment: @jodag I'm using cross entropy. If that's the case, what should I use as a reference for early stopping or in choosing the model?

Comment: I don't think cross entropy can drop to zero. This would imply that logits take values of either + or - infinity. Even if training accuracy reaches 100% the confidence of predictions can still get better (approaching 1 for the correct class and 0 for incorrect classes) which may continue improving the model.

Comment: Od course, it may be possible for it to be exactly zero due to floating point errors but I would be honestly surprised if this were the case.

Comment: @jodag I don't think it's going to drop to 0 either. The validation loss decreases gradually. Validation loss is around 30 right now and it's dropping by 0.001 every epoch so far